# How to upgrade a python class to take an array instead of a float?

Tags: python, class, init

I have defined a class which performs the way I want on a single element, but when I want to pass an array, it raises an error:

```
ValueError: The array returned by a function changed size between calls
```

How the code below (this is a simplified version for test purposes) can be updated so it can return an array of elements once it receives an array of elements? I don't want to use a for or while loop and iterate through the elements of the array.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

T, Tpc, Ppc = 235, 410, 700

class PVT():

    def __init__(self, pressure=None):
        self.pressure = pressure

    def z_factor(self):
        Tpr = ((T -32) * (5/9) +273.15)/(Tpc*5/9)
        Ppr = self.pressure/Ppc
        tr = 1/Tpr

        A = 0.06125 * tr * np.exp(-1.2 * (1 - tr) ** 2)
        B = tr * (14.76 - 9.76 * tr + 4.58 * tr ** 2)
        C = tr * (90.7 - 242.2 * tr + 42.4 * tr ** 2)
        D = 2.18 + 2.82 * tr

        #Y-func = (Y + Y^2 + Y^3 + Y^4)/(1 - Y)^3 - APPr - BY^2 + CY^D 
        Y_func = lambda Y : ((Y + Y ** 2 + Y ** 3 - Y ** 4) / ((1 - Y) ** 3)) - A * Ppr - B * Y ** 2 + C * Y ** D
        Y_sol = fsolve(Y_func, 0.5)
        return A*Ppr/Y_sol

p1 = np.array([100, 500, 1000])

f = PVT(p1)
print("z-factor is: %s" %(f.z_factor()))
```

Comment: use `self.pressure = pressure.copy()` instead of `self.pressure = pressure` and see if it works

Comment: @Anwarvic it raised the same error once redefine self. the way you suggested.

Comment: Could you add a comment with `Y_func` in mathematical form?

Comment: @Anwarvic I added a comment and wrote the Y-func in mathematical form.